# Javascript - How would you make a record unique by adding a number?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Right now when file already exist I added prefix which is a timestamp to the filename to make it unique.

But instead of using timestamp I want to use ordinal suffix or add a number to the filename.

I would add an incremented number to the filename if the file exists. But can't quite wrap my head around how to do this in a good way.

Using timestamp works but its too long like when we display the filename it would be like for example so instead of using timestamp I just want to increment a number to a filename.

`Hellworldfilename - 1593024232` - timestamp is too long , not a good idea.

It should based from existing records in  the database . If for example I add a file with filename Hellworldfilename and it already existed then the new filename would be Hellworldfilename-1 , and if I add Hellworldfilename again the new filename would be Hellworldfilename-2 and so on and so forth. Any idea how we can make a filename everytime unique ?

Let me give an example. let us say I have 3 files in the database with filesname

```
DOC
DOC-1
DOC-2
```

If I add a file with filename DOC the new filename would be now DOC-3.

#Code for checking if file exists

```
const file = await context.service.Model.findOne({
    where: { humanId: record.id, filename: data.filename },
    paranoid: false,
  });

if (file) {
    const prefix = Date.now().toString();
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    const fileParts = data.filename.split('.');
    filename = `${fileParts[0]}-${prefix}.${fileParts[1]}`;
```

Comment: Use a uuidv4 as example ?

Comment: The problem is that I display those filenames on the front-end and seeing names with long UUID is not a good idea .

Comment: for example the filename would be Helloworldfilename-123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000 if I use UUID ,, thats too long.

Comment: Write in the db a "user friendy name"  and store the file on the file system as a uuid string.

Comment: is inserting a number to a filename really hard Sir ? wouldnt it be simpler?

Comment: You can use as file name what ever you want (as long the file system allows it), but your soultion is not really elegant. With seperate fileds in the db you can display to the user the original name, as he uploaded the file, and store it unique as uuid on the hdd/ssd.

Comment: Nope , you dont get it . my issue is that whenever a filename already exist on the database I wanted to increment 1 number to the file. so for example if I add a file with filename Marc and marc already exist the filename of the new file I have added would be now Marc-1 and so and so forth

Comment: Thats just terrible, but, where is the problem ?

Comment: the problem is that if I keep adding a file with the same filename I cant track the number I am going to add to the filename

Comment: as you can see on my example above     filename = `${fileParts[0]}-${prefix}.${fileParts[1]}`;        I used a timestamp as a prefix , but as what I have told you , I just wanted to add a number rather than a whole timestamp string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219040/discussion-between-marc-and-mr-mark-tawin).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check whether the filename ends with -somenumber. If so, then you can extract that number and increment it. Otherwise put 1 into the result:

```
function getNumberedFileName(fileN) {
    //These are value initializations to cope with the situation when the file does not have a .
    var fileName = fileN;
    var fileExtension = "";
    var lastDotIndex = fileN.lastIndexOf(".");
    if ((lastDotIndex > 0) && (lastDotIndex < fileN.length - 1)) { //We are not interested in file extensions for files without an extension hidden in UNIX systems, like .gitignore and we are not interested in file extensions if the file ends with a dot
        fileName = fileN.substring(0, lastDotIndex);
        fileExtension = "." + fileN.substring(lastDotIndex + 1);
    }
    var lastDashIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf("-");
    if ((lastDashIndex > 0) && (lastDashIndex < fileName.length - 1)) {
        var lastPart = fileName.substring(lastDashIndex + 1);
        if (!isNaN(lastPart)) {
            var index = parseInt(lastPart) + 1;
            return fileName.substring(0, lastDashIndex) + "-" + index + fileExtension;
        }
    }
    return fileName + "-1" + fileExtension;
}
```

Comment: aint that the filename should be based from the existing ones in the database ? for example let us say there are existing files with filenames DOC and DOC-1 in the database , If I add file with filename DOC again it should check first for existing before adding a number right ? so that based on my example above the new DOC would be now DOC-2.

Comment: @Mr.MarkTawin you have not provided any information about your database, hence I have written a function that is able to find the next filename given a filename exists. If you want us to work on your database, then you will need to show how your database looks alike.

Comment: I have updated my question Sir , also have have example on querying data on the database , please check sir , thanks

Comment: @Mr.MarkTawin since I do not have any information about your actual database, you can store your filenames in a table with the structure of filenames(id, filename), you can search for select filename from filenames order by id desc limit 0, 1 (assuming it's MySQL). If there is no record, then you use your filename for the first time. If there is a record, then you can call the function above by passing the filename.

Comment: Nope I mean the query I added o nthe question works but my problem is not solved yet.

Comment: @Mr.MarkTawin please imagine yourself into the situation of the answerers. We only have the information you provide. We cannot guess the information you have not provided. As about the image you gave to me, it seems that you have some duplicated filenames and some timestamped filenames already. You will need to tidy your data before my idea applied in this answer can be used.

Comment: Let me give an example. let us say I have 3 files in the database with filesnames (DOC,
DOC-1,
DOC-2) . If I add a file again with filename DOC the new filename would be now DOC-3. this is the problem I am trying to solve Sir

Comment: @Mr.MarkTawin Have you tested my function with DOC-2? It returns DOC-3, the exact value you need. So you will only need to be able to find out that DOC-2 is the last name for DOC. I have provided you ideas for that, but your question is **not** providing enough information for us to help you with your database. The best information is provided by your imgur image, linked here in the comment section, but there, in the third row we can see a filename starting with DOC and already ruined by a long time string. As I have already stated, you need to provide information. You need to tidy your data.

Comment: I need to know what your **exact** try is to find out what the last filename was, what the response is, what my function returns for that, why is it incorrect and what should the value be instead.

Comment: there is no problem with your function  , but it should based on the record on the database or will check first the record in the database for adding number to a filename. Let me give an example. let us say I have 3 files in the database with filesnames (DOC, DOC-1, DOC-2) . If I add a file again with filename DOC the new filename would be now DOC-3.

Comment: @Mr.MarkTawin how are you trying to get that value from the database?

Answer (score 0):

You could declare an object `filenames` in the global scope like

```
const filenames={};
```

and use it for keeping track of already opened files.

Below I defined a function `makeUnique()` hilighting the ideas I mentioned here before. It turns out I had to tweak my code a little bit but here is a working snippet:

```js
const makeUnique=(function(){
 const filenames={};
 return function(fn){
  const fileParts=fn.split(".");
  const prefix=filenames[fn]!=null
  ? ++filenames[fn]
  : filenames[fn]=0;
  if (prefix) fileParts[Math.max(fileParts.length-2,0)]+='-'+prefix;
  return fileParts.join('.')
 }
})();

console.log(["abc","d.e.f.c","abc","ghi","abc","abc.txt","def",
             "abc.txt","d.e.f.c","abc.txt","abc"].map(makeUnique))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important}
```

I used an IIFE to generate a protected scope for the static object `filenames`. This is now accessible by all calls of `makeUnique()` but otherwise "private", i. e. cannot be modified accidentally from anywhere else.

Comment: what is the +a ⁹0?

Comment: can you explain me sir how this solves the problem ?>

Comment: I was posting from my smartphone, sorry, fixed it!

Comment: I assumed that you are talking about files being opened multiple times in a single session. In this case the `filenames` object will help you to create meaningful prefixes.

Comment: Your solution sir fails when I have the samefilename for morethan 3 times . for example if i add a file with filename cars no problem to it since no file with that the same name , and then i add again file with filename cars and new filename now would be cars-1 which works fine , but If I add again cars it would be a problem already since it will be based on cars rather than on cars-1 so instead of cars-2 the algo above will just creat another cars-1

Comment: Have you tried it? It should create prefixes with increasing numbers, as long as the global context for `filenames` remains active.

Comment: It was only able to create prefixis based on the first added file. If I add a filename for the firstname let us say DOC and then I add DOC again so the new filename now is DOC-1 but If I add DOC again the created prefix is still DOC-1 rather than DOC-2